# MLastLocation always returns the same location

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3

(First of all excuse for my english, I'm from Spain).

I'm working on an Android App with Android Studio with Google Maps API. I want to make a button that draws a circle in my current position. But, if I move and I press the button again, I want it to draw another circle on my new position, keeping both sircles on screen.
Button works fine drawing circles, but my problem is that, although I'm moving and changin my position, if I press the button it keeps drowing the circles at the same location. It doesn't refresh my location.
I'm setting circle .center Latlng with MLastLocation. I guess this could be the problem.
Any solution?
Thanks.

My Maps.Activity.java code:

```
package com.example.borja.pruebamapa1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
Button bcirculo;
Button bborde;
Button bborrar;
private Circle circle;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private TextView mLatitudeText;
private TextView mLongitudeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    bcirculo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcirculo);
    bborde = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bborde);
    bborrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bborrar);

    bcirculo.setOnClickListener(this);
    bborde.setOnClickListener(this);
    bborrar.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(6000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bcirculo:
            Circle circulogrande = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                    .radius(200)
                    .strokeWidth(0)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(40, 0, 255, 0))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(40, 0, 255, 0))
            );
            Circle circulopeque = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                    .radius(70)
                    .strokeWidth(0)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(20, 255, 0, 0))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(20, 255, 0, 0))
            );

            break;
        case R.id.bborde:
            Circle bordefuera = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                    .radius(200)
                    .strokeWidth(20)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255))
            );
            Circle bordepeque = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                    .radius(70)
                    .strokeWidth(0)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 255, 0))
            );
           break;
        case R.id.bborrar:
            mMap.clear ();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you should be using removeLocationUpdates in "onLocationUpdates". 
You could try this instead.
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-gps-with-locationmanager-to-get-current-location-example/

Comment: Yeah!, thanks. That was the problem.